# replaceAll() not working as expected and passing value outside a helper thread to main thread

Tags: java, android, html, multithreading

Two problem:

**Solved** Replaced $ with another special character @ and it solved the problem.
**Problem 1**
I have a variable `String strVar` which contains below text (which it has read from a file). Now I am trying to use `replaceAll()` to replace texts (e.g. `$pixeltrackers$` with `"sampletext"`) but it is not replacing this particular string at all, maybe due to quotes and spaces etc. What can be a possible solution?

```
<html>
    <head>
        $pixeltrackers$
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="$clickurl$"><img src="$iconurl$"/></a><h1>$headlinetext$</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>$descriptiontext$</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="$clickurl$"><img src="$mainurl$"/></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Rating: $ratingtext$</h3>
            <form action="$clickurl$">
                <input type="submit" value="$ctatext">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h6>by: $advertisertext$</h6>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Problem 2**
I have a thread with a *try-catch block*. Inside the try block I have the HTML stored in a variable which I want to load into a webview. Now Android/Java doesn't allow Webview to be called any other place apart from main thread.

How can I pass this String variable value outside the scope of thread?

Comment: are you doing this: String.replaceAll($pixeltrackers$, NewText) or StringB = StringA.replaceAll($pixeltrackers$, NewText).  String#replaceAll returns a new String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem1**

[String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes the `String` representation of a regular expression as its first argument.

The `$` character is a special character for regex, signifying the end of the input. 
Escape it as `\\$` to quote it as literal.

Otherwise, use `String.replace`, which doesn't take a regular expression.

**Problem2**

Ask a new question and post your code.

Comment: String.replace will replace multiple instances of a particular substring pattern?

Comment: @kafan1986 yes. All of them. See [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29). **Edit** not a substring pattern, a substring literal to be more precise.

Comment: @kafan1986: `String.replace will replace multiple instances of a particular substring pattern?` this question would be best asked directly to the documentation.